# mockk, what is just run

Tags: kotlin, mockk

Could not find explanation about the "just run", what does it mean when stub a function with it?

Will it make the mock object to call its real function, or make the function run a stub which does nothing?

Is there sample for showing some real use case?

```
@Test
fun `mocking functions that return Unit`() {
    val SingletonObject = mockkObject<SingletonObject>()
    every { SingletonObject.functionReturnNothing() } just Runs. // ???

    SingletonObject.otherMemberFunction(). //which internally calls functionReturnNothing()
    //...
}
```

with or without this `every { SingletonObject.functionReturnNothing() } just Runs` stub, the test is doing same.

Comment: Hopefully, https://notwoods.github.io/mockk-guidebook/docs/tips/unit/ will answer your question.

Comment: sorry, it did not.  what does it "When stubbing a function that returns nothing, MockK provides a few shortcuts." mean?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Copy of the answer from @Raibaz:

`just runs` is used for methods returning `Unit` (i.e., not returning a value) on strict mocks.

If you create a mock that is not relaxed and invoke a method on it
that has not being stubbed with an `every` block, MockK will throw an exception.

To stub a method returning Unit, you can do

```
every { myObject.myMethod() } just runs
```

No, it doesn't (like mockito's .thenCallRealMethod()) :)
It "just runs", meaning it does not do anything.

To run the real method you can use:

```
every { ... } answers { callOriginal() }
```